# I cannot write the correct split function for an assignment to parse a given email to print out the first name of the email recipient

Tags: python-3.x

Below is what I have in my python file. I think that the output is what the assignment is looking for but I have my doubts since I may be misreading it. This is my first programming class.

Assignment: parsefrom.py

CIS 156 Python I

Write a function to read through mailbox data like the sample below and when you find

line that starts with "From", you will split the line into words using the split function.

We are interested in who sent the message, which is the second word on the From line.

```
find_email_name = "From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008"
x = find_email_name.split()
    
print(x[1:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use indexing, select the item at index 1:

```
find_email_name = "From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008"
x = find_email_name.split()
    
print(x[1])
```